# windows bat file using start cmd /k with doskey not work

Tags: windows, cmd

I tried to use start cmd with custom doskey file, but failed.

1.doskey

```
ls=dir /b $1
```

`start "title" cmd.exe /k doskey /macrofile=1.doskey && ls .`

Prompted

`ls command is not recognized`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

#### Issue 1

The `&&` will be interpreted by the shell you run this command *from* and not the shell in the window, so you are running `doskey /macrofile=1.doskey` in the new window but `ls .` in the old one.

The solution is to surround the whole command that should be passed to the new window with doublequotes:

```
start "title" cmd.exe /k "doskey /macrofile=1.doskey && ls ."
```

Alternatively you could escape both `&` characters with `^`:

```
start "title" cmd.exe /k doskey /macrofile=1.doskey ^&^& ls .
```

...however, this will just uncover issue 2, so keep reading.

#### Issue 2

As you can deduce (sort of) from the [DOSKEY docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey), you cannot run a macro from a command that you didn't type in manually (after all, DOSKEY is a tool to process *interactive* input from a user):

> To run a macro, type the macro name at the command prompt, starting at the first position. If the macro was defined with $* or any of the batch parameters $1 through $9, use a space to separate the parameters. **You cannot run a doskey macro from a batch program.**

(Emphasis mine.)

This talks only about batch files, but it applies to any non-interactive way of entering a command - and passing it to `cmd /c` or `cmd /k` is one of them (since you aren't typing the command into the new shell, it's run automatically on startup of the shell instead).

Based on how you described your intent ("use start with custom doskey file"), I assume you added the `ls .` only to test whether it works. In that case, just remove the whole `&& ls .` part and try `ls .` manually in the new window, and you'll see that it does work!

In case that's not what you wanted, and you actually intended to run DOSKEY macros from that "cmd /k" command line or a batch file, you are out of luck - instead, you could call a batch file that contains functions and use that, or create custom batch files instead of macros.

Comment: Thanks, but still not work. `ls command is not recognized`

Comment: Right, I see. You cannot use DOSKEY with commands entered non-interactively. Added to my answer.